# How to send JSON with umlauts (ü, ö, ä) over RestEASY to my server?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, resteasy

I am trying to send a JSON Object via RestEASY (which uses jackson to encode the String to my pojo) and POST from my Client to my Server.

Both have a pojo called MessageDto.

The Client has the jackson libary (core, annotation, databind all 2.2). With this it's generate a JSON String out of my pojo. Afterwards i send it to my Server.

It works fine.

But only if there is no Umlaut or ß...

Server:

```
@Path("/rest")
public interface MessageService {
  @POST
  @Path("/add")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Response add(@Context
  HttpServletRequest servletRequest, MessageDto message);
}
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
  @Override
  public Response add(@Context
  HttpServletRequest servletRequest, MessageDto message) {
    System.out.println("MessageServiceImpl: add " + message);
    return Response.status(Status.CREATED).build();
  }
}
```

Client:

```
public abstract class MessageSender {
    public static void send(MessageDto m) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String urlParameters = mapper.writeValueAsString(m);

            System.out.println(urlParameters);

            String request = "http://localhost:8080/MyProject/rest/add";
            URL url = new URL(request);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();

            int response = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(response);

            wr.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Syso of my urlParameters (MessageDto as JSON):

```
{"id":null,"title":"Müsli","receiverIdList":[],"category":"cereals","priority":"HIGH","content":"Müsli Müsli Mjam Mjam Mjam","functionList":[]}
```

---

I get this error:

```
13:47:01,670 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Failed executing POST /rest/add: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@65d397; line: 1, column: 23]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:202) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:124) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:147) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@65d397; line: 1, column: 23]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidInitial(Utf8StreamParser.java:2796) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidChar(Utf8StreamParser.java:2790) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString2(Utf8StreamParser.java:1972) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString(Utf8StreamParser.java:1899) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.getText(Utf8StreamParser.java:276) [jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:26)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:13)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:61) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
   ... 26 more
```

The log says, that there is some invalid utf-8. But why? I use jackson on both sides...

btw: without 'ü' it works fine:

```
14:02:26,128 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) {"id":null,"title":"Musli","receiverIdList":[],"category":"cereals","priority":"HIGH","content":"Musli Musli Mjam Mjam Mjam","functionList":[]}

14:02:26,133 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) MessageServiceImpl: add MessageDto [id=null, title=Musli, receiverIdList=[], category=cereals, priority=HIGH, content=Musli Musli Mjam Mjam Mjam, functionList=[]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is

```
 wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
```

If we read the API:

```
public final void writeBytes(String s) throws IOException
```

*Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the length of s.*

You can use:

```
public final void writeUTF(String str) throws IOException
```

which *writes a string to the underlying output stream using modified UTF-8 encoding in a machine-independent manner.*

Another option is converting the string to bytes with `urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");` and write them using directly the OuputStream given by the connection.

Comment: Thanks the urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8") did the job :)